# Uniform Distribution - Show an Expression is Uniform on (a, b)

Tags: statistics, random-variables

I'm not quite sure how to deal with this problem. I'm thinking it has to do with uniform random variables in that

f(x) = 1/(b-a)  if a <= x <= b

Otherwise, f(x) = 0.

The question would be: If U is uniformly distributed on (0, 1), show that

a + (b - a)U

is uniform on (a, b).

However, if it does have to do with a uniform random variable, I'm unsure how to actually use it. Can someone please give me an explanation on how to go through with this, or if I'm thinking about the problem in the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A distribution is uniquely determined by its cumulative distribution function.  So, one way to approach this problem is to show that the CDF of $a+(b-a)U$ is exactly the CDF for $\text{Uniform}(a,b)$.

To do this, you need to compute $P(a+(b-a)U\leq x)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Consider three separate ranges: $x\leq a$, $x\in(a,b)$, and $x\geq b$. In each case, use algebra to rewrite the event $\{a+(b-a)U\leq x\}$ in terms of an inequality for just $U$.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. How would we apply these ranges to the problem? Could you complete one as an example, please?

Comment: Because you know that $U$ is $\text{Uniform}(0,1)$, you know $P(U\leq u)$ for any $u\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$
P(U\leq u)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{if }u\leq0\\ u & \text{if }0<u<1\\ 1 & \text{if }u\geq 1\end{cases}
$$
You can also compute what this function (the _cumulative distribution function_) looks like for $\text{Uniform}(a,b)$. Then, what remains is to show that $P(a+(b-a)U\leq x)$ takes exactly this last format.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that P(U <= u) = F(u). How would I compute what the CDF looks like for Uniform(a, b) such that P(a + (b - a)U <=x) takes after that CDF (if I'm reading what you're writing correctly)?

Comment: You can use algebra to rewrite "$a+(b-a)U\leq x$" as an inequality for $U$, then use the definition of the CDF for $U$ that you already know.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**ALTERNATIVE WAY :**

Consider the Characteristic Function of $a+(b-a)U$

\begin{align}
E(e^{it(a+(b-a)U)}) &= e^{ita}E[e^{i(t(b-a))U}]\\&=e^{ita}\dfrac{e^{it(b-a)}-1}{it(b-a)}\\&=\dfrac{e^{itb}-e^{ita}}{it(b-a)}
\end{align}
This implies $a+(b-a)U$ is a unifrom on $(a,b)$