# For a, b in (−∞, ∞), a < b, show that Y = a+(b−a)X has a uniform distribution over [a, b].

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, uniform-distribution, moment-generating-functions

Let X be uniformly distributed over the interval [0, 1]
For a, b in (−∞, ∞), a < b, show that Y = a+(b−a)X has a uniform distribution over [a, b].

How would you approach this problem?

[Uniform Distribution - Show an Expression is Uniform on (a, b)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276652/uniform-distribution-show-an-expression-is-uniform-on-a-b)

This link has an approach to this question but couldn't understand the steps for the moment generating function?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why one would use MGF for this . You get it from definition: $P(Y<c)=P(X<\frac {c-a} {b-a}) =\frac {c-a} {b-a}$ for $c$ between $a$ and $b$ and this is the definition of uniform distribution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am curious about the alternative ways to answer this question. How can I apply the definition to Y = a+(b−a)X  case. Thank you in advance.